# Bugzilla: Code on start

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi

I tried to install Bugzilla on my Raspberry. Everything is greater than the minimum system requirements and I installed perl lib to apache too, but I got this when I wanted to "run" it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#
# This Source Code Form is "Incompatible With Secondary Licenses", as
# defined by the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0.

use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(. lib);

use Bugzilla;
use Bugzilla::Constants;
use Bugzilla::Error;
use Bugzilla::Update;

# Check whether or not the user is logged in
my $user = Bugzilla->login(LOGIN_OPTIONAL);
my $cgi = Bugzilla->cgi;
my $template = Bugzilla->template;
my $vars = {};

# And log out the user if requested. We do this first so that nothing
# else accidentally relies on the current login.
if ($cgi->param('logout')) {
    Bugzilla->logout();
    $user = Bugzilla->user;
    $vars->{'message'} = "logged_out";
    # Make sure that templates or other code doesn't get confused about this.
    $cgi->delete('logout');
}

# Return the appropriate HTTP response headers.
print $cgi->header();

if ($user->in_group('admin')) {
    # If 'urlbase' is not set, display the Welcome page.
    unless (Bugzilla->params->{'urlbase'}) {
        $template->process('welcome-admin.html.tmpl')
          || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
        exit;
    }
    # Inform the administrator about new releases, if any.
    $vars->{'release'} = Bugzilla::Update::get_notifications();
}

if ($user->id) {
    my $dbh = Bugzilla->dbh;
    $vars->{assignee_count} =
      $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bugs WHERE assigned_to = ?
                             AND resolution = ''", undef, $user->id);
    $vars->{reporter_count} =
      $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bugs WHERE reporter = ?
                             AND resolution = ''", undef, $user->id);
    $vars->{requestee_count} =
      $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bug_id) FROM flags
                             WHERE requestee_id = ?', undef, $user->id);
}

# Generate and return the UI (HTML page) from the appropriate template.
$template->process("index.html.tmpl", $vars)
  || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
```

What I missed? Or should I use an another issue tracker? (MantisBT)

Comment: That's not an error message, it's a part of the source code....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "run it" you mean "Visited an HTTP URL pointing to your Raspbery Pi on the network in a web browser" and that by "this" you mean "The source code of the CGI program was rendered in the browser" then:

You haven't configured Apache to support CGI for whereever you installed Bugzilla.

The [Apache manual page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html) covers how to do this in detail.

You'll need to start by loading the module:

```
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
```

and enabling CGI for the location you put Bugzilla:

```
<Directory "/path/to/bugzilla/">
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is helped me

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla.conf
```

Paste in the following and save:

```
ServerName localhost

<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

```
$ a2ensite bugzilla

$ a2enmod cgi headers expires

$ service apache2 restart
```

Referral URL:
https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html#configure-apache